A problem about Fourier analysis
Let $f$ be a bounded function and the period of the $f$ is $2\pi$, it is piecewise monotonic on $(-\pi,\pi)$. Let $a_n,b_n$ present its fourier coefficient. Can we find a constant $L$ that for every $n$ , we have
$$
|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_k\cos kx+b_k\sin kx| \leq \frac{L}{n}
$$
If we can't, what about a piecewise linear function? Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
